# Is the sum of all elements of the residual matrix equal zero under OLS?

Tags: least-squares, residuals

I have the following OLS model

$$ y_i= α+βx_i+ε_i  , i = 1,...,N $$

I want to prove that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N e_je_k =0$$

I did the following

$$ \sum_{k=1}^N  (e_1+e_2+e_3+...+e_n) e_k $$
$$ = (e_1+e_2+e_3+...+e_n) (e_1+e_2+e_3+...+e_n) $$
$$ = (e_1^2+e_2^2+e_3^2+...+e_n^2+...+2e_1e_2+2e_1e_3+2e_2e_3+...)  $$

$$= \sum_{i=1}^N e_i^2 +2\sum_{j=1,j\neq k}^Ne_je_k , $$

At this point i am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The thing you wrote down as "normal equations" obviously is not an equation, so you might want to start by fixing that up.  Note, too, that $\sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Ne_je_k=\left(\sum_{i=1}^Ne_i\right)^2$, so all you need to show is that $\sum_{i=1}^Ne_i=0$.

Comment: Ok I fixed that;however, I am not sure how you got the result you just mentioned. Isn't double summation with two different indexes means that the first series is computed then repeated again for the second one.

Comment: The second line in "I did the following" says *exactly the same thing*: the double sum is the square of the sum.